# AADB2C900080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again on iOS/MAUI

Tags: c#, ios, azure-ad-b2c, maui, azure-ad-msal

I am receiving the error, only for one iOS deployment so far, `AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again.` on the following call on the call to MSAL `await ClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent`:

```
public async Task<RunesPostResponse?> ProcessImage(byte[] imageBytes, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    try
    {
        RunesPostResponse? resp = null;
        var accounts = (await ClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync(SignInSignOutPolicy)).ToList();

        var result = await ClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(new string[] { ApiScope },
 accounts.First()).WithForceRefresh(true).ExecuteAsync(token); //exception on this line
        using (var client = Create())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                var response = await client.PostAsync("process_image/", content, token);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var raw = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<RunesResponseRaw>(cancellationToken: token);
                    if (raw != null)
                    {
                        resp = new RunesPostResponse();
                        resp.Annotations = raw.annotations;
                        resp.Success = raw.success;
                        resp.AnnotatedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(raw.annotatedImage);
                    }

                }
            }
            

            
        }
        return resp;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Before calling this code the following code is successfully executed (as interactive):

```
    public async Task DoLogin(bool forceInteractive = false, CancellationToken token = default)
    {

        bool tryInteractive = false;
        if (!forceInteractive)
        {
            try
            {
                var accounts = (await ClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync(SignInSignOutPolicy)).ToList();
                if (accounts.Any())
                {
                    var result = await ClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(new string[] { ApiScope }, accounts.First()).ExecuteAsync();
                    IsLoggedIn = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.AccessToken);
                    tryInteractive = !IsLoggedIn;
                }
                else
                    tryInteractive = true;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                tryInteractive = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Alert.Handle(ex.Message).GetAwaiter();
            }
        }
        else
            tryInteractive = true;
        if (tryInteractive)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await ClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(new string[] { ApiScope })
                            .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount).ExecuteAsync(token);
                IsLoggedIn = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.AccessToken);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Alert.Handle(ex.Message).GetAwaiter();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I tried running the following code, thinking it was a iOS Keychain caching issue and it did not solve the issue:

```
        private async void ReactiveContentPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
#if IOS
        SecureStorage.Default.RemoveAll();
#endif
        }
```

Comment: That result is a normal case. If `AcquireTokenSilent` fails with that status you need to take the user back through the interactive login process.  It indicates that their refresh token is no longer valid; One potential reason is that their password has been changed/reset or has expired.

Comment: @Paulw11 : I login with interactive on app load and I tried to do it again when a MsalException is raised when calling slient: same error

Comment: When you re-try the interactive auth, does it actually take the user through the interactive process or does it just fail with the error?  Is it affecting only one user or all users for your app.  If it is one user then they may have a problem with their account. If it is all users for your app then you should check the application registration in Entra ID.

Comment: @Paulw11: it does take them through the apple login interactive (twice) and it provides an AccessToken: but once it trys silent the AccessToken is invalid. It seems to just be happening for one device. I tried creating a new Apple Service Id and that did not resolve the problem.